Tiering value in RFQ
I was wondering what are typical strategies employed by market making firms to calculate the tiering value of each client.
So when a client create an RFQ, the market maker after calculating the BID/ASK will apply a scaling factor the tiering value depending on the client. Hence offering better prices for non-toxic clients and bad prices for toxic clients.
What are typical strategies to calculate this tiering value and hence client toxicity in RFQs?
One idea I had was to utilize historical data, mark-to-market at, let's say, 5s the PnL of all trades made for each client, and measure the skewness of that distribution. Then, we rank each client based on that skewness. If the client's skewness falls within the lower quantiles, we will consider the client as toxic; otherwise, as non-toxic. Does that type of strategy works? or there are more complex strategy and more accurate methodologies to learn that tiering value?
